# Blank screen in Ubuntu 13.10 after login; missing opengl

Tags: 13.10, opengl, opencv

I had aworking Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop till yesterday when I installed OpenCV 2.4.  It did not cause any immediate problem yesterday but when I turned on the power this morning, I did not get a desktop after I logged in.  I do get the login screen fine with my appropriate background.

I went into text mode using CTRL-ALT-F1 and logged in.  When I did `startx`it went on for a while and got stuck at `Loading extension GLX`.

I typed the command `unity` which gave me an error `compiz (core) - Error: Plugin 'opengl' not loaded`.

I have looked at other posts and even reinstalled `xserver-xorg-video-intel` but no luck.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and after searching for hours i got the solutions. Just follow these simple steps :

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+F1
2. Provide Login details
3. type     `sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*`
4. type     `sudo reboot`
5. Done!

Enjoy !